# Extjs 4.1 tabpanel not showing data

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

am newbie to Extjs. presently am using Extjs 4.1.1a for some application.
I have defined following tabpanel in my application.

```
    Ext.require('Ext.tab.*');

    Ext.onReady(function(){

    var tabs2 = Ext.widget('tabpanel', {

    activeTab: 0,
    width: 600,
    height: 250,
    plain: true,

    defaults :{
        autoScroll: true,
        bodyPadding: 10
    },
    items: [{

            title: 'Ajax Tab 1',
            loader: {
                url: 'dynamic.html',
                contentType: 'html',
                autoload: true,
                loadMask: true,
                scripts: true
            },
            listeners: {
                activate: function(tab) {
                    tab.loader.load();
                }
            }
        },{

            title: 'Ajax Tab 2',
            loader: {
                url: 'group_associator.html',
                contentType: 'html',
                autoload: true,
                loadMask: true,
                scripts: true
            },
            listeners: {
                activate: function(tab) {
                    tab.loader.load();
                }
            }

        },
        {

            title: 'Ajax Tab 3',
            loader: {
                url: 'group_disassociator.html',
                contentType: 'html',
                autoload: true,
                loadMask: true,
                scripts: true
            },
            listeners: {
                activate: function(tab) {
                    tab.loader.load();
                }
            }

        }
    ],
    renderTo : Ext.getBody()
 });
 });
```

here i have used Three html files in loader config. my problem is on executing , first tab is working perfectly.but in case of other two tabs namely Ajax Tab 2,Ajax Tab 3 , only one is showing data perfectly. i have made activeTab=0 so first tab will be active by default. but in case if i select second tab, it will work correctly then if i select third tab it will not show any data. but, after refreshing the page if i select third tab it will show data correctly ,and now if i select second tab , it will not show any data. in all case default active tab i.e Ajax Tab 1 will show data correctly.so, only one tab will work perfectly for every refresh i.e either Ajax Tab 2 or Ajax Tab 3.

following is the html file where tabpanel will render to.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Tabs Example</title>
    <!-- Ext includes -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-4.1.1a/resources/css/ext-all.css"    />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-4.1.1a/ext-all.js"></script>

    <!-- Shared example includes -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext- 4.1.1a/examples/shared/example.css" />

    <!-- Example includes -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tabs.css" />

    <!-- GC -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="tabs1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="tabs1">
    </div>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

i want all three tabs to show data perfectly on selecting.
can anyone please help me out of this. :)

Comment: I am new to ExtJs. I tried your script. Everything is working fine except one thing. When I click on any tab which has been loaded using Ajax, other tabs get disabled i.e. I am not able to click on them.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the tabchange event. That should work.

ex:

```
'tabchange': {
    fn: function(tab) {
        tab.loader.load();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was using the same div ids in all the HTML files which are used to render the content of JavaScript files. To resolve my issue, I made my div ids unique.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the above options did not work (Did not work for me)..I tried adding  'layoutOnTabChange:true' to my Tabpanel and I could see the contents.